# How to manage Local Notification in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7, uilocalnotification

I am creating local notification when app receiving Push notification. these local notification generating when app in foreground and when i am creating local notification at the same time didReceiveLocalNotification method is calling and getting difficulties to manage local notification and clicking/tap on location same event calling twice.I need to avoids duplicate Local notifications also.

Please help me for solve this issue.

```
 //MARK: - Delegate Method For APNS Notification
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        print("Notification Message \(userInfo)")

        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]

        // 1
        if  userInfo["postData"] != nil {

            // Refresh Promotions 
            print("Got it...")

        // Clear Previous Value Data
        postData.removeAll()

        //Adding New Post Data here
        if (userInfo["postData"] != nil){
            self.postData = userInfo["postData"]! as! [String : AnyObject]
            print(self.postData)
        }

        //Condition here for Notification
        if appInForeground == false {

            //Goto Promo List
            //Set Boolean for View
            notiDetails = true

            //Navigation
            gotoPromoListView()
        }else{

            let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016
            // to play sound
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertBody = (aps["alert"] as? String)!
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            notification.userInfo = userInfo["postData"]! as! [String : AnyObject]
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

#### How to manage this method for local notification

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
        // Do something serious in a real app.
        print("Received Local Notification:")
        print(notification.userInfo)
        self.postData = notification.userInfo as! [String : AnyObject]
        didTapNotification()
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are setting the local notification when you receive the push notification?

Comment: In foreground condition i need to show this notification.

Comment: You mean, you want to do something when you receive the remote notification and the app is in foreground mode?

Comment: Exactly i am receiving APNS push notification in this case i need to show Local notification only in foreground condition and remove old one local notification from same "userInfo"  because it is creating duplicate local notification and didReceiveLocalNotification this method calling on same time when i am creating Local notification so i need to avoid it method should works on only tap on notification.

Comment: Is there any specific way that you want to show local notification when you receive the remote notification as the delegate for the remote notifications gets called even if the app is in foreground or background mode?

Comment: This is managed pretty cool by [BSForegroundNotification](https://github.com/kunass2/BSForegroundNotification)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show your code, where you register your remote notifications?

If you want to show alert and badge, when receive push notifications, you can make like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        return true
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

After that you can add custom actions to method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : 
}
```

If you need local notifications, you should set fire property, when you schedule notification:

```
let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
      localNotification.fireDate = NSDate()
      localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
      localNotification.alertBody = text
      localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Comment: I don't need this in my code everything is working fine only i want to manage local notification not want to create. @Anton.

Comment: For handling notifications duplicates, you can assign some unique identifier to every notifications, for userInfo["ItemID"], for example.
Then, when you schedule local notification, you cycle through all created notifications using:
let allNotifications = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications!
    for notification in allNotifications {
}

And if there's notification with itemID already used, it's duplicate, and you cancel this notification and schedule it again.

If I correctly understand your question.